# How to build the Darling project on Ubuntu?

Tags: compiling, software-sources

The [Darling project](http://darling.dolezel.info/en/Darling) is an open source Darwin/OS X emulation layer for Linux. I downloaded the source code with git and tried to build it with `cmake` but it failed. The document says I need these packages:

```
clang 3.1+
GCC 4.6+ (yes, you still need GCC for header files)
libkqueue
libbsd
gnustep-base ("Foundation")
gnustep-gui ("Cocoa")
gnustep-corebase ("CoreFoundation")
libobjc2
libudev
openssl
libasound
libav
libgc
```

But I could not find them on `apt` or in Software Center. Also `cmake` showed this result:

```
No build type selected, default to Debug
This is a 64-bit build
Building ObjC ABI 2
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library Carbon without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library AppKit without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library auto without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBGNUSTEPCOREBASE_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/motool
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/util
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libmach-o
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libdyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/dyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/dyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libSystem
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libltdl
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Cocoa
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libobjcdarwin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreFoundation
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libncurses
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreSecurity
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreServices
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/ExceptionHandling
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/IOKit
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Foundation
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Carbon
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreVideo
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/OpenGL
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/thin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/thin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libstdc++darwin
LIBKQUEUE_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/motool
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/util
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libmach-o
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libdyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/dyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/dyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libSystem
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libltdl
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Cocoa
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libobjcdarwin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreFoundation
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libncurses
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreSecurity
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreServices
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/ExceptionHandling
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/IOKit
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Foundation
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Carbon
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreVideo
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/OpenGL
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/thin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/thin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libstdc++darwin
LIBOBJC2_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/motool
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/util
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libmach-o
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libdyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/dyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/dyld
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libSystem
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libltdl
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Cocoa
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libobjcdarwin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreFoundation
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libncurses
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreSecurity
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreServices
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/ExceptionHandling
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/IOKit
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Foundation
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/Carbon
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/CoreVideo
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/OpenGL
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/thin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/thin
   used as include directory in directory /home/mirror/work/darling/darling/src/libstdc++darwin

Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How can I build the Darling project?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps described in http://darling.dolezel.info/en/Build/Ubuntu

Skip the Multilib sections.

I have needed two extra (not mentioned in the manual) packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libltdl-dev libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Then go back to an ordinary build http://darling.dolezel.info/en/Build#Ordinary_Build

Answer (score 0):

You can use my PPA to install darling. Don't forget to add the GNUstep PPA, which includes multiarch packages of the needed GNUstep libraries, so you'll be able to have dyld32 and dyld64.

https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/darling